# Confusion about localization

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am a bit confused about the following result I read:
Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space. Let $\left\{X_t\right\}_{t\in[0,T]}$ be a continuous and adapted process on this space taking values in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $X$ is locally bounded in the sense that there is a localizing sequence $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of stopping times (which satisfies $\tau_k\leq\tau_{k+1}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and for each $\omega\in\Omega$ there is some $n_\omega\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\tau_n(\omega)=T$ for all $n\ge n_\omega$) such that the stopped process $X(\cdot\wedge\tau_k)$ is bounded (in fact: $|X(t\wedge\tau_k)|\leq k$).

Now, my confusion comes: Let's take the filtration $\mathfrak{F}$ to be constant $\mathfrak{A}$. Suppose there is some $Z\in L^{1}(\mathbb{P})\setminus L^2(\mathbb{P})$. If I then define the continuous, adapted process $X$ by $X_t\equiv Z$ I arrive at the local boundedness of this process: For the described sequence of stopping times I get $|Z|=|X(t\wedge\tau_k)|\le k$. But doesn't this imply that $Z$ is square-integrable which I excluded?

Can somebody tell me why and where I am wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In the conditions for $(\tau_n)$ to be localizing, one should read that the stopped processes $$\mathbf 1_{\tau_n > 0}\,X^{\tau_n}$$ are each uniformly bounded, not the processes $X^{\tau_n}$ themselves. Then your example is indeed locally bounded, as shown by the stopping times $$\tau_n=\inf\{t\geqslant0\mid |X_t|\geqslant n\},$$ since, with this choice, $$\mathbf 1_{\tau_n > 0}\,X^{\tau_n}=\mathbf 1_{|Z|<n}\,Z.$$

Comment: @Did thank you for your answer. What do you mean by "one should read"? I mean, what I wrote in my question cannot be right, but where is the mistake?

Comment: "One should read" means that the definition in your post is incorrect because you forgot (or the text you are following mistakenly omits) the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{\tau_n>0}$.

Comment: @Did Ok, this is completely new to me: The definition of a local property $\Box$ of a stochastic process $X$, e.g. on $[0,T]$ is the following: There is a nondecreasing sequence of stopping times $(\tau_k)$ such that $\tau_k(\omega)=T$ for all but finitely many $k$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$ such that the stopped process $X(\cdot\wedge\tau_k)$ has property $\Box$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No. What is your text? https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/localization/

Comment: Some lecture notes...but we assumed that the filtration at time 0 is trivial. Thank you! I've learnt something new which is consistent with the things I knew before.

Comment: You can consider answering your own question, so that it appears as answered. :)